# Instagram access token made live from sandbox mode without invite users.?

Tags: php

I need to fetch public instagram feeds for my developement site but my sandbox-mode instagram access token only returns the empty result. Is there any way to fetch pubic feeds using my access token.?

(or)

Is there any way to become Live mode from sandbox without invite users.?
Thanks in advance..